# Displaying Query String (URL) filter result on Page

Tags: 2013, url, query-string, parameter

I have a Query String (URL) filter on my SharePoint 2013 page that is currently passing a string parameter which I then use to filter a list. This list is displayed in a view on my web part page.  I want to add a "Title" object above my list view to show the value of the filter parameter that I'm passing to filter the list.

Does anyone know how I can do this?  I looked through the web part options that were available to add, and couldn't find one to simply display the result of the query string filter.

Comment: Use GetUrlKeyValue('queryStringParamKey') javascript method to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

So, continuing from @sekhar's comment above, I added a `Script Editor` below the `Query String (URL) Filter` with the following contents:

```
Region: <span id="RegionSpan"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
var region = GetUrlKeyValue('Region');
var span = document.getElementById('RegionSpan');
span.innerHTML = region;
</script>
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you want to put the title. If you want to put it at the main title of the aspx, open it in the advanced mode. Look for the `PlaceHolderPageTitle` and customize the body of it. In my case in order to have a link on the page itself and print an Url-Parameter I did:

```
<a href="">
    <script language="javascript"> document.write('Aufgaben ' + GetUrlKeyValue('Urlparameter'));</script>
</a>
```